# Modify PDF to display multiple slide per page with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, gd, ghostscript

I have a PDF, let's assume with 10 pages.

I search a script that will modify this PDF to display 4 slide per page (in fact, x slide per page).
So in the end, the output will be a PDF with 3 pages (Page 1 with 1-2-3-4, page 2 with 5-6-7-8 and page 3 with 9-10.

I would like to do this from PHP, so I can use Ghostscript, ImageMagick, GD, ...

Do you know a tool that can do this ?
Thank you !

Comment: Ghostscript is in fact perfectly capable of N-up printing, see https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Page_parameters -sNupControl. But this question is actually off-topic because it isn't programming, it's a request for recommendations.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, the problem was I wasn't using the correct terms. I didn't manage to make it work with Ghostscript (yet), but I used Imagemagick and it went well : "montage input.pdf -tile 2x2 -geometry +5+5 -page A4 output.pdf"

Comment: If it's working with IM then I wouldn't look any further :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the quality is not always good. Depending on the source PDF, the result can be pixelized. For GS, i tried : gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNEWPDF -sPAPERSIZE=A4 -o output.pdf  -sNupControl=2x1 input.pdf . There's a result, but it's the input pdf, without any change, I don't understand why :/

Comment: Without seeing the input I can't really comment and that's not my code area. You could open a bug report and someone will look at it. As far as I know it is supposed to work. (assuming you are using a reasonably recent version of Ghostscript, old versions don't have the feature)

Comment: Again, thanks for your help, I upgraded my Ghostscript to the latest version, but it did not change anything. I managed to generate a good quality result, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used 2 commands to create what I wanted.

```
pdftoppm input.pdf output -png
```

To generate images from my pdf. This way, I keep the quality intact.

```
montage output-*.png -tile 2x2 -geometry +4+4 -page A4 output.pdf
```

To generate the PDF.

This commands works well for a 2x2 generation, but to create a 2x1, I wanted landscape, so I forced the page with size

```
montage output-*.png -tile 2x1 -geometry +4+4 -page 842x594 output.pdf
```

With these 3 commands, the output of the file is what I wanted and the quality is the same as the original PDF.

If you want to generate multiple PDF files, don't forget to remove the images between each PDF !